# How can I suppress the JSHint "JSCS: Illegal Space" warnings in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, jshint, jscs

We're using JSHint in a Visual Studio 2013 solution. When building, we are seeing some formatting warnings for items that break style warnings, but are functionally valid.  Specifically, I would like to suppress the "Illegal Space" warnings.  I consider warnings like this in the build error list visual chaff:

- JSCS: Illegal space before opening curly brace
- JSCS: Illegal space
  before opening round brace

Here's why.  I'm a fan of using the Visual Studio auto-formatting feature (Ctrl+K+D).  In a scenario where a function is defined as follows...

```
$select.find('option').each(function(){
```

... the auto formatting feature will change it to this:

```
$select.find('option').each(function () {
```

JSHint is valuable for finding other problems, like missing semicolons, so I'd prefer to continue using it in this project.  There is a settings file via Web Essentials > Edit Global JSHint Settings.  But it's unclear to me what setting in that file I need to adjust to suppress those Illegal Space warnings.

=== Update 4/6/2015 ===

Based on the recommendation from Mike C below, the fix I applied is as follows:

1. Select Web Essentials > Edit global JSCS Settings.
2. Search for these strings in the .jscsrc file, and set their related properties to false:  "RoundBrace", "CurlyBrace".
3. Close and reopen Visual Studio 2013 with your solution.
4. Rebuild and those warnings will disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't a JSHint error, it's a JSCS error. Under the Web Essentials menu click `Edit global JSCS settings (.jscsrc)...`. Look for `requireSpacesInAnonymousFunctionExpression` and change `beforeOpeningRoundBrace` to `false`.

See this [JSCS reference](http://jscs.info/rules.html) for a list of all of the rules and their values.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Changing that didn't affect the build notifications for me.  For instance, this line of script was flagged with a "JSCS: Illegal space before opening round brace" warning. showStatusChangeAlert = function (externalUserID, action)

Comment: Oh, I see other references to "beforeOpeningRoundBrace" in that file. I'll flag them to false and see what happens...