# How to supress the error : Illegal space before opening round brace at from jsrc?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, jshint, lint

In our angularjs project, after up-gradation of gulp3 to 4 and when i run : `gulp lint`

```
C:\filepath>gulp lint
[12:59:30] Using gulpfile ~\filepath\gulpfile.js
[12:59:30] Starting 'lint'...
app\js\app.config.js: line 4, col 1, Use the function form of "use strict".

1 error
Illegal space before opening round brace at C:\filepath\app\js\app.config.js :
     7 |angular
     8 |    .module('test')
     9 |    .config(['localStorageServiceProvider', function (localStorageServiceProvider) {
C:\filepath>gulp lint
[12:59:30] Using gulpfile ~\filepath\gulpfile.js
[12:59:30] Starting 'lint'...
app\js\app.config.js: line 4, col 1, Use the function form of "use strict".

1 error
Illegal space before opening round brace at C:\filepath\app\js\app.config.js :
     7 |angular
     8 |    .module('test')
     9 |    .config(['localStorageServiceProvider', function (localStorageServiceProvider) {
```

I am not able to figure out, everything was working fine earlier. Only after the gulp upgradation to latest one, build is failing. Can anybody please assist me with this.

I also followed this link : [How can I suppress the JSHint "JSCS: Illegal Space" warnings in Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172748/how-can-i-suppress-the-jshint-jscs-illegal-space-warnings-in-visual-studio-20).

According to the link above, i tried adding below lines inside .jshintrc file:

```
"requireSpacesInAnonymousFunctionExpression": {
    "beforeOpeningCurlyBrace": false
},
"disallowSpacesInNamedFunctionExpression": {
    "beforeOpeningRoundBrace": false
},
"disallowSpacesInFunctionDeclaration": {
    "beforeOpeningRoundBrace": false
}
```

Its throwing more error following the previous:

```
6 code style errors found.
app\js\app.module.js: line 0, col 0, Bad option: 'requireSpacesInAnonymousFunctionExpression'.
app\js\app.module.js: line 0, col 0, Bad option: 'disallowSpacesInNamedFunctionExpression'.
app\js\app.module.js: line 0, col 0, Bad option: 'disallowSpacesInFunctionDeclaration'.
app\js\app.module.js: line 4, col 1, Use the function form of "use strict".
```

What i require here is:

My Editor webstorm automatically applying space for alignments as mentioned below:

```
function (localStorageServiceProvider) // with space
```

But, it should be:

```
function(localStorageServiceProvider) // without space
```

What is the exact rule i need to apply in .jshintrc file or any other places which fixes...?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I resolved this adding : `"excludeFiles": ["**/*"]` in `.jscrc` file. Final version of `.jscrc` file looks like :

```
{
  "preset": "google",
  "fileExtensions": [ ".js" ],

  "maximumLineLength": 120,
  "validateIndentation": 4,

  "disallowSpacesInAnonymousFunctionExpression": null,

  "excludeFiles": ["**/*"]
}
```

Comment: Now you are not linting anything. Better just get rid of jshint altogether.

Answer (score 2):

If you would prefer, you can configure Webstorm not to insert the spaces. I don't have Webstorm here, but in IntelliJ IDEA (same underlying IDE) the option is under

`Preferences`->`Editor`->`Code Style`->`Javascript`->`Spaces`->`Before Parentheses`->`In function expression`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @CupawnTae. But there are so many files, we did not face such kind of issue till date. More than 100 people working in our project and i cant say them to change the settings in webstorm which sounds ackward now. And i am also facing error as: `Line must be at most 120 characters at C:\filepath\somanyfiles.js`. Any help w.r.to jshint global suppression will be much appreciated and thank u once again

Answer (score 0):

The lint rules you need to configure are:

```
"requireSpacesInAnonymousFunctionExpression": {
    "beforeOpeningRoundBrace": true,
    "beforeOpeningCurlyBrace": true
}
```

and

```
"requireSpacesInFunctionExpression": {
    "beforeOpeningRoundBrace": true,
    "beforeOpeningCurlyBrace": true
}
```

Comment: Error: `2 errors
filepath\file.js: line 0, col 0, 
Bad option: 'requireSpacesInAnonymousFunctionExpression'.
filepath\file.js: line 0, col 0, Bad option: 'requireSpacesInFunctionExpression'.
`

Comment: You have to load these rules.You can find the rules here: https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/tree/master/lib/rules